# Assembly x86 MASM loop analysis

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, masm, irvine32

The following is a piece of loop code I am trying analyze and understand how loops work:

```
;the ecx register is the loop counter

  mov ecx,6
  mov edx, offset space 
myloop:
  mov eax,ecx
  dec eax
  call writedec 
  call writestring 
loop myloop 
  call crlf 

  mov ecx,6
  mov edx, offset space 
myloop2:
  mov eax,6
  sub eax, ecx 
  call writedec
  call writestring 
loop myloop2
```

My questions are:

1. What does `offset space` mean?
2. What does `mov edx, offset space` mean?
3. I don't understand how the `offset space` is the source?
4. How do you move register `ecx` into register `eax`?
5. Why is the `offset space` the source and register `edx` the destination?

Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: "offset space" looks like its a variable/constants that's been defined earlier in the code.
"mov edx, offset space " copies the value of the variable into the edx register

Comment: i apologize but i don't understand how that is a variable. I am very new to assembly. Thanks

Comment: If you don't know how to move one register into another, you should really read a book or tutorial before asking questions. It's pretty much the first thing you learn.

Comment: @JoeBourne: `offset space` gets the address as an immediate, not the value as a load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `offset` operator returns the offset of a memory location relative to the beginning of the segment (DS in the case of `MOV`) to which the location belongs (see [here](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/lecture.html#I77_0180_offset_operator)). `space` is likely a variable that's defined somewhere earlier in the code, so that `offset space` would return the number of bytes relative to the beginning of the segment (usually the `DS` data segment) to that variable.

In other words, `mov edx, offset space` will copy a pointer to the `space` variable (of type `DWORD`, 32-bit) to be placed in the `edx` register. The reason it's placed in `edx` must be found in the `writedec` and `writestring` routines.

As for the loop you're asking about, that's where the `ecx` register comes in. The `loop` instruction will cause the code pointer to move to its destination as long as `ecx` is not zero, decreasing it by 1 immediately before checking it. The loop value is also used by your code somewhere, which is why it's copied to `eax` so that other code will not change the value of `ecx` and mess up your loop.

Comment: It's still just `DS`; not `EDS`.  Segment registers in protected mode index into the Global Descriptor Table of segment *descriptors*, instead of being plain values that are shifted and added.  I wouldn't even mention segmentation in an answer that asks how to move one register to another.  In normal code (not 16-bit), OFFSET just gets the address.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yesterday I did the "evil" deed of incorporating the 
rectifying aspects of your objection into the answer. I hope you will approve of that :-)

Comment: @zx485: that's generally a good thing.  I was lazy and didn't do it myself.  (Partly because I wanted to suggest that Alex should remove most of the first paragraph to keep it simple (segmentation can be pretty much ignored outside of 16-bit mode), so that would not be a good edit.)